# Unexpected results when multiplying in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to make a simple BCD --> binary conversion operation work in an ALU I'm coding. All the other operations work perfectly fine, just this last operation doesn't work for some reason.

I've tried numerous approaches and nothing seems to make sense.

My inputs are `A` and `B` which are both 8-bit vectors.  The outputs are `X` and `Y`.

So the formula goes `Y:X = BCD2BIN(B:A)`.

In my case, in my testbench I have `B = 0x40` and `A = 0x46`, so the output I'm expecting is `0xFCE`, which is 4046.

Just for those who are unaware, the simplest way to perform this is to divide each byte into 2 nibbles, and multiply by a constant and sum the terms.

So:

`B:A = 0x4046 = (4 * 1000) + (0 * 100) + (4 * 10) * (6 * 1)`

**Signals I'm Using**

```
B = 0x40  --These are the inputs of the ALU, so it isn't actually coded this way.
A = 0x46  --However these are the values.

signal sig1000 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := x"03E8"; --1000
signal sig100 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := x"0064";  --100
signal sig10 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := x"000A";  --10

signal dig1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal dig2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal dig3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal dig4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
```

After the BEGIN

```
dig1 <= B(7 downto 4);
dig2 <= B(3 downto 0);
dig3 <= A(7 downto 4);
dig4 <= A(3 downto 0);
```

**Actual Operation**

```
opF <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((unsigned(dig1) * unsigned(sig1000)) + (unsigned(dig2) * unsigned(sig100)) + (unsigned(dig3) * unsigned(sig10)) + (unsigned(dig4)));
```

And later the opF gets split into Y and X.

So even verifying the signals in simulation, they are correct, yet the output is not.

The `sig10001`, `sig100` and `sig10` are the correct values, and `dig1 = 4`, `dig2 = 0`, `dig3 = 4` and `dig4 = 6` with unsigned decimal radix.

Yet the result is **252**

I've even tried this using constants, instead of vectors, with even less success.

For example

```
opF <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((unsigned(dig1) * 10#1000#) + (unsigned(dig2) * 10#100#) + (unsigned(dig3) * 10#10#) + (unsigned(dig4)));
```

**Full file**, as some have requested.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity ALU is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
       OPCODE : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       Y : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       X : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       Z : out  STD_LOGIC;
       Cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
       V : out  STD_LOGIC;
       F_active : out  STD_LOGIC;
       X_bin_pal : out  STD_LOGIC;
       X_prime : out  STD_LOGIC;
       N : out  STD_LOGIC);
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is

    signal resultSignal : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);

    signal cin_vector : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 downto 0);

    signal op0 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op5 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op6 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op7 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op8 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal op9 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal opA : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal opB : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal opC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal opD : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal opE : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal opF : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);

    signal dig1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    signal dig2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    signal dig3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    signal dig4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);

    signal Xsig : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := x"00";
    signal Xsig_reverse : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := x"00";

    signal Ysig : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := x"00";

    signal Zsig : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal Coutsig : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal Vsig : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal Nsig : STD_LOGIC := '0';

    signal sig1000 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := x"03E8";
    signal sig100 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := x"0064";
    signal sig10 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := x"000A";



begin

cin_vector(0) <= Cin;

dig1 <= B(7 downto 4);
dig2 <= B(3 downto 0);
dig3 <= A(7 downto 4);
dig4 <= A(3 downto 0);

op0 <= x"00" & (A AND B);
op1 <= x"00" & (A OR B);
op2 <= x"00" & (A XOR B);
op3 <= x"00" & (A XNOR B);
op4 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(x"00" & A) + unsigned(x"00" & B));
op5 <= x"00" & STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(signed(A) + signed(B));
op6 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(x"00" & A) + unsigned(x"00" & B) + unsigned(x"000" & "000" & cin_vector));
op7 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(signed(A) * signed(B));
op8 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(A) * unsigned(B));
op9 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(x"00" & A) - unsigned(x"00" & B));
opA <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ROTATE_LEFT(unsigned(A & x"00"), 1));
opB <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ROTATE_LEFT(unsigned(Cin & A & "0000000"), 1));
opC <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SHIFT_RIGHT(unsigned(A & x"00"), 1));
opD <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SHIFT_RIGHT(signed(A & x"00"), 1));
opE <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SHIFT_LEFT(unsigned(A & x"00"), 1));
opF <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((unsigned(dig1) * unsigned(sig1000)) + (unsigned(dig2) * unsigned(sig100)) + (unsigned(dig3) * unsigned(sig10)) + (unsigned(dig4)));

with OPCODE select resultSignal <=
     op0 when x"0",
     op1 when x"1",
     op2 when x"2",
     op3 when x"3",
     op4 when x"4",
     op5 when x"5",
     op6 when x"6",
     op7 when x"7",
     op8 when x"8",
     op9 when x"9",
     opA when x"A",
     opB when x"B",
     opC when x"C",
     opD when x"D",
     opE when x"E",
     opF when x"F";


Ysig <= resultSignal(15 downto 8) when OPCODE = "0111" or OPCODE = "1000" or OPCODE = "1111" else
        x"00";

Y <= Ysig;

Xsig <=     resultSignal(15 downto 8) when OPCODE = "1100" or OPCODE = "1101" or OPCODE = "1110" else
            resultSignal(15 downto 9) & resultSignal(0) when OPCODE = "1010" else
            resultSignal(14 downto 8) & resultSignal(0) when OPCODE = "1011" else
            resultSignal(7 downto 0);

Xsig_reverse <= Xsig(0) & Xsig(1) & Xsig(2) & Xsig(3) & Xsig(4) & Xsig(5) & Xsig(6) & Xsig(7);

X <= Xsig;

Zsig <=     '1' when resultSignal = x"0000" else
        '0';

Z <= Zsig;

Coutsig <=  resultSignal(8) when OPCODE = "0100" or OPCODE = "0110" or OPCODE = "1001"  or OPCODE = "1110" else
            resultSignal(15) when OPCODE = "1011" else
            resultSignal(7) when OPCODE = "1100" or OPCODE  = "1101" else
            '1' when OPCODE = "1111" and  Ysig /= x"00" else
            '0';

Cout <= Coutsig;


Vsig <=     '1' when OPCODE = "0101" and resultSignal(7) = '0' and A(7) = '1' and B(7) = '1' else
            '1' when OPCODE = "0101" and resultSignal(7) = '1' and A(7) = '0' and B(7) = '0' else
            '1' when OPCODE = "1110" and resultSignal(15) /= A(7) else
            '0';

V <= Vsig;

F_active <= Zsig OR Coutsig OR Vsig;

X_bin_pal <=    '1' when Xsig = Xsig_reverse else
                    '0';

X_prime <=  '1' when Xsig = x"02" or Xsig = x"03" or Xsig = x"05" or Xsig = x"07" or Xsig = x"0B" or Xsig = x"0D" or Xsig = x"11" or Xsig = x"13" else
                '1' when Xsig = x"17" or Xsig = x"1D" or Xsig = x"1F" or Xsig = x"25" or Xsig = x"29" or Xsig = x"2B" or Xsig = x"2F" or Xsig = x"35" else
                '1' when Xsig = x"3B" or Xsig = x"3D" or Xsig = x"43" or Xsig = x"47" or Xsig = x"49" or Xsig = x"4F" or Xsig = x"53" or Xsig = x"59" else
                '1' when Xsig = x"61" or Xsig = x"65" or Xsig = x"67" or Xsig = x"6B" or Xsig = x"6D" or Xsig = x"71" or Xsig = x"7F" or (Xsig = x"83" and Nsig = '0') else
                '1' when (Xsig = x"89" or Xsig = x"8B" or Xsig = x"95" or Xsig = x"97" or Xsig = x"9D" or Xsig = x"A3" or Xsig = x"A7" or Xsig = x"AD") and Nsig = '0' else
                '1' when (Xsig = x"B3" or Xsig = x"B5" or Xsig = x"BF" or Xsig = x"C1" or Xsig = x"C5" or Xsig = x"C7" or Xsig = x"D3" or Xsig = x"DF") and Nsig = '0' else
                '1' when (Xsig = x"E3" or Xsig = x"E5" or Xsig = x"E9" or Xsig = x"EF" or Xsig = x"F1" or Xsig = x"FB") and Nsig = '0' else
                '0';

Nsig <= '1' when OPCODE = "0101" and Xsig(7) = '1' else
        '1' when OPCODE = "0111" and Ysig(7) = '1' else
        '1' when OPCODE = "1101" and Xsig(7) = '1' else
        '1' when OPCODE = "1110" and Xsig(7) = '1' else
        '0';

N <= Nsig;



end Behavioral;
```

Comment: VHDL is very context sensitive. Can you give us a complete, self-contained source file that demonstrates the problem, instead of fragments of source code that have been pulled from your project?

Comment: how opF is defined?

Comment: The entire source is added.

Comment: Are you sure your OPCODE is correct? Can you see the value of opF, not the result?

Comment: My VHDL is very rusty, but I would say that the problem is related to the sizes of the vectors you're multiplying. For example, dig1 is 4 bits and sig1000 is 16 bits. So probably the implementation is truncating bits when performing this operation.

Comment: Yeah the OPCODE is fine it is `1111` but no, `opF` is the incorrect value of `242`

Comment: @RogerC. I have also tried a version with: `unsigned(x"000" & dig1)` and so on cause I wondered the same thing.  That was also unsuccessful. If you'd like me to post waveforms of each of these cases, I can gladly do that as well

Comment: 252 in binary is 11111100 while 4046 is 111111001110. You are getting the correct value except for the missing last 4 bits.

Comment: @RogerC. Thanks that's a great clue! I will look at that closer.

Comment: Are you observing the result on the `resultSignal` or on one of the outputs?

Comment: On `resultSignal`, before splitting it into `Y` and `X`. And on `opF` as well.

Comment: I'll upload a picture of my waveforms here in a second.

Comment: Because 16 bits multiplied by 4 bits could become, at most, a 20 bits number, this is I guess the size implicitly created by VHDL for storing the result of the multiplication. And when this implicit 20 bits number is assigned to a 16 bits array, the last 4 bits are lost. Could you try to resize opF to a 20 bits size vector?

Comment: Alternatively you could "downsize" sig1000, sig100 and sig10 to a 12 bits size array.

Comment: "Alternatively, you could downsize ...". This. Roger, you may want to post an answer.

Comment: Thanks alot.  Turns out that was the problem! Resized them to 12 bits and removed the 12 bit pre-pending and it's all good now. I still have quite a bit to learn about vector multiplication! I would accept that as the answer, Roger.

Comment: You're welcome! I posted my answer too. Actually Brian Drummond also deserves the credit, discovering the fact that the compiler was complaining abound "bound array error" pointed clearly to the root of the problem!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

16 bits multiplied by 4 bits can become, at most, a 20 bits number, this is apparently the size implicitly created by VHDL for storing the intermediate result of the multiplication.  When this implicit 20 bits number is assigned to a 16 bits array, the last 4 bits are lost. And that's why Brian Drummonds's VHDL simulator complained about bound array error.

Because your final result actually fits in a 16 bits number, the best workaround is to reduce the number of bits of sig1000, sig100, sig10 to a 12 bits array.

Comment: Let's be clear : implicit behaviour is not what VHDL is about. And now we know why. So much time has been wasted on this question, thanks to a tool problem. Unfortunately this tool defect does VHDL's reputation no favours, though a decent tool would have flattened this mountain into a minor speed bump.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, sure, a good tool should had pointed this out, supposedly VHDL is a strongly typed language!

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to do, as always, is to write a testbench. Here's a minimal one (below). Note I used a VHDL-2008 "to_string" call to simplify it.

Now, analyze, elaborate and simulate...

```
ghdl -a --std=08 alu.vhd
ghdl -a --std=08 alu_tb.vhd
ghdl -e --std=08 ALU_TB
./alu_tb
./alu_tb:error: bound check failure at alu.vhd:89
./alu_tb:error: simulation failed
```

So the problem is an array bound violation in line 89 ... which is, of course, `opF <= ...`

Which simulator can't diagnose a simple bounds violation? Ditch it and get a better one. Or find out how to turn the bound checks on. (If it's Xilinx ISIM, there's an option that should never have been off in the first place).

But now that you know it's a simple array bound error it should be dead easy to find and fix. Start by running just one digit at a time through that big calculation.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity ALU_TB is
end ALU_TB;

architecture TB of ALU_TB is

constant A : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := X"46";
constant B : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := X"40";
constant Cin : STD_LOGIC := '0';
constant OPCODE : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := X"F";
signal Y : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal X : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin

DUT : entity Work.ALU
Port Map( 
       A         => A,
       B         => B,
       Cin       => Cin,
       OPCODE    => OPCODE,
       Y         => Y,
       X         => X,
       Z         => open,
       Cout      => open,
       V         => open,
       F_active  => open,
       X_bin_pal => open,
       X_prime   => open,
       N         => open);

check : process is
begin
   wait for 1 us;
   report "X = " & to_string(X) severity NOTE;
   report "Y = " & to_string(Y) severity NOTE;
end process check;

end TB;
```